# Как построить правильно архитектуру для обновления статусов активности/невидимости элементов формы?

Tags: архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования

В моей ИС есть модуль в виде формы с 10-12 элементами (панели, комбобоксы, баттоны). Этот модуль достаточно "низкоуровневый" - используется в составе десятка (а то и больше) других модулей. Также в ИС широкое дерево прав пользователей, и бывают различные требования бизнес-логики, которые могут влиять на активность/невидимость кнопок.

Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы отрефакторить часть кода формы, отвечающей за видимость/активность кнопок, чтобы и в будущем можно было легко поддерживать код на предмет добавление новых требований на видимость.

То есть видимость/активность кнопок зависит от модуля, содержащего мою форму, прав пользователя (причем и от комбинации прав), требований бизнес-логики. При этом любое из перечисленных требований может затрагивать как один элемент, так и несколько за раз. На первый взгляд, сейчас на каждый элемент формы воздействует комбинация до 15-20 требований.

Прошу советов и напутствий, как можно реализовать архитектуру для удобного добавления требований, в какие паттерны проектирования стоит посмотреть и применить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем и целом я посоветовал бы обратиться к книге Эрика Эванса [Предметно-ориентированное проектирование (DDD)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5497184/), а конкретно к главам, посвящённым *регламенту*. Вкратце — вынесение регламентов (требований) в отдельный набор классов хорошо подходит в случае, когда эти регламенты потребуется часто менять или дописывать.

Возможно, лишний раз я бы подумал об уровне (layer) этих регламентов. Очень может быть, что они относятся к представлению, а к не к бизнес-логике. Но, возможно, часть из них должна быть размещена на уровне бизнес-логики, а часть — на уровне представления.

Answer (score 0):

То что вы описываете это типичный конечный автомат. Рекомендую две вещи:

- Видео [Почему сложно программировтать UI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCeNCr2tKOI)
- Книга [Автоматное программирование](http://is.ifmo.ru/books/_book.pdf)

Заодно вы познакомитесь с паттернами State и State machine, описанными в книге выше.